# Why did the Doctor think he was going to die in "The Time of the Doctor" even though he saw Capaldi in "The Day of the Doctor"?

Tags: doctor-who, the-day-of-the-doctor

The 13th Doctor, Capaldi, showed up in "The Day of the Doctor" when the Doctors froze Gallifrey.

So, if the 12th Doctor saw him back then, how come he thought he was the last Doctor at the episode "The Time of the Doctor"? Could he have just forgotten?

Comment: Even more compelling - he had a phone conversation with Clara in the future wherein he talks about taking care of "him", "him" being the new Doctor. Wibbly, wobbly...

Comment: @Chris B. Behrens - in "Time of the Doctor", Eleven learns that he has been granted a new regeneration cycle before actually regenerating, so he could have called Twelve between this and the moment he regenerates. See the transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-16.html), the line is "CLARA: You're young again. You're okay. You didn't even change your face. 
DOCTOR: Ha! It's started. I can't stop it now. This is just the reset. A whole new regeneration cycle. Ooo."

Comment: But he was ancient at that point. His call, if we are to accept the visual onscreen in the episode (which Clara wouldn't have been able to see), was made before he received the regenerations.

Comment: @Chris B. Behrens - no, note Clara's line "You're young again" and his response "This is just the reset" -- if you watch the scene you'll see the 11th Doctor had become young-looking when Clara found him in the Tardis and those lines were said, apparently a "reset" in apparent age is something that happens shortly before a regeneration (or at least it *can* happen--there seemed to be no reset for John Hurt's "War Doctor", who we saw looked much younger in "Night of the Doctor" when the 8th Doctor first regenerated into him).

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens  He made the call after blowing up the Daleks but before actually regenerating.

Comment: Ah, I see. The plot contrivances we Who fans accept...

Comment: @Dave Um no he blew up the Daleks *with regeneration energy*. It was obviously already in progress. Watch the Doctor's expression when he receives his new regeneration cycle: he knows what's happened.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, but then he goes into the TARDIS to actually regenerate.  He does not regenerate at the top of the tower when he uses the regeneration energy to blow up the Daleks.  Daleks go boom, he makes a phone call, then he goes into the TARDIS to regenerate.

Comment: @DaveJohnson: The whole thing is a regeneration. Where do you think the explosive energy came from?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can't even.  If you read my comments, you know I am aware it is regeneration energy.  Sure, the whole thing is the regeneration.  But at some point, he actually completes it.  Crap like this is why no one likes us.

Comment: @DaveJohnson: "Crap like this"? Why are you being so rude? The point is that Eleven knew he was able to regenerate, _because he was regenerating_. So Chris's implication that it must have been "wibbly wobbly" for Eleven to chat to Twelve is wrong; there's nothing "wibbly wobbly" about it at all: Eleven knew that Twelve was coming, by the time of the phone call, because he'd just blown up an entire Dalek starship using the regeneration energy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, I'm the one being rude here.  Okay.  Your first comment to me said nothing of the sort.  Chris's implication was already taken care of, as he himself accepted the explanations that Hypnosifl and I gave (months ago, I might add).  "Crap like this," is the ridiculous argument over semantics that you started.  Yes, the regeneration started, hence regeneration energy to blow up the Daleks.  But he had not *actually* regenerated yet.  But rather than spend 300 chars to explain that, I simplified it in away everyone would understand.

Comment: @Dave Nice talking with you.

Answer (score 17):

**TL; DR: Yes, it's possible that during *Time of the Doctor*, the Eleventh Doctor has forgotten his future self's involvement in the saving of Gallifrey.**

To add to the answer by Hypnosifl and to answer the specific part of your question "Could he have just forgotten?", remember that the War Doctor and the Tenth Doctor (and by extension, the Ninth) don't retain the memories because of the muddled time streams, but the Eleventh does, because it's his present. Capaldi's appearance, though, would be from his future, and so it's *entirely* likely that he doesn't remember it for the same reason.

Maybe it's that Time Lords can't generally retain memories of interactions with their future selves. This is a consequence of the [Blinovitch Limitation Effect](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Blinovitch_Limitation_Effect) shown with the Brigadier in *Mawdryn Undead* -- the younger version can't remember the interaction with the older. It also explains why the Fifth Doctor doesn't recall being pulled into the Death Zone in *The Five Doctors* despite having been there three times previously. (I say "generally" because it seems like the Second Doctor remembers the events of *The Three Doctors* during his conversation with the Brigadier in *The Five Doctors*. However, since the Time Lords deliberately brought the three incarnations together, they may have had some way to circumvent the effect.)

Granted, the events of *Time Crash* seem to contradict that since it implies that the Fifth Doctor would remember watching the Tenth fix the TARDIS, but that could be explained by the memories of the younger simply being suppressed until he "catches up" with the future events. So he does remember, he just doesn't *remember* that he remembers until he's on the other side of the conversation; that is, when he's Ten.

This also accounts for Eleven's line in *Day of the Doctor*, "This is where I come in." That implies that he remembers meeting his future self when he was Ten, in spite of explicitly saying that Ten won't remember. The memories are still *there*, just inaccessible until the most forward point in the timeline. At the point where the time streams cross, Eleven suddenly has access to the memory his past self made, leading him to remark, essentially, "Oh, right! This happened. I'd forgotten."

Comment: I thought the Brigadier's memory loss in *Mawdryn Undead* was due to *touching* his older self, which released a "massive discharge of energy" and knocked both versions unconscious. Are there any other examples to suggest that the younger versions of the Doctor don't retain a memory of multi-Doctor meetings? In *The Five Doctors*, when the 2nd Doctor met up with the Brigadier, he recalled their earlier adventure with Omega--but that happened in another multi-Doctor story, *The Three Doctors*. Also, the resolution to *Time Crash* depended on 5's memories of the meeting still being in 10's head.

Comment: 1) The energy surge was definitely the result of the contact, but we don't know if the memory loss would still have occurred regardless. 2) The Time Lords specifically and deliberately brought the first three Doctors together in *The Three Doctors*. They may likely have had some way to mitigate the effects of the Limitation. 3) That's why I said Five's memories were simply suppressed until they caught up with the relative present. He had the memories, but couldn't access them until he was Ten because they were memories of his future.

Comment: Good points, I didn't read your last two paragraphs carefully enough. Looking at the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/34-1.htm) it was actually the War Doctor that was told by Eleven that he wouldn't remember, but that suggests that at least in Day of the Doctor the writers were thinking of multi-Doctor meetings not being remembered by younger versions, even if writers of earlier episodes may not have thought that way.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Also explains why Ten doesn't know why Queen Elizabeth is mad at him in *The Shakespeare Code*... when we know from *Day of the Doctor* it's because he married her and then disappeared for decades (from her perspective)... although that could just be because Ten was meeting her in reverse order from his perspective...

Comment: @Adeptus - Yes, I think it's the second option, it seems like the 10th Doctor in *Day of the Doctor* was supposed to be from an adventure sometime between *The Waters of Mars* and *The End of Time* (well after *The Shakespeare Code*), since at the beginning of *End of Time* he seemed to say he'd gone around having a bunch of adventures to procrastinate in replying to Ood Sigma's psychic summons, and that one of those adventures involved marrying Queen Elizabeth.

Comment: From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-17.htm): "I was summoned, wasn't I? An Ood in the snow, calling to me. Well, I didn't exactly come straight here. Had a bit of fun, you know. Travelled about, did this and that. Got into trouble. You know me. It was brilliant. I saw the Phosphorous Carousel of the Great Magellan Gestadt, saved a planet from the Red Carnivorous Maw, named a galaxy Alison. **Got married. That was a mistake. Good Queen Bess. And let me tell you, her nickname is no longer.** Ahem." (Elizabeth's nickname was "The Virgin Queen" BTW)

Comment: Nice. I remembered several scenes from the show that indicated your answer was the correct one, but the act of upvoting your answer caused me to forget I remembered. Of course, obviously now that I'm typing this I remembered the moment when I forgot I remembered.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there was any on-screen evidence that the 11th Doctor noticed the presence of the 12th, only one of the Time Lords on Gallifrey commented on the appearance of a thirteenth Tardis beyond the ones belonging to the first eleven numbered "Doctors" along with the Tardis of the incarnation played by John Hurt (whatever you want to call him, since fans seem to have agreed on the convention that he won't be referred to as a numbered "Doctor"). From the transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/34-1.htm), the lines from two Gallifreyans in that scene are:

> GENERAL: I didn't know when I was well off. All twelve of them!
>
> ANDROGAR: No, sir. All thirteen!
>
> (A new pair of grey eyebrows is seen.)

Later, in the shot with all the Doctors standing together, Capaldi's 12th Doctor doesn't appear (though it doesn't really matter anyway, since as someone pointed out to me on another answer, this scene was actually described by Eleven's narration as a dream):

[image]

Comment: "whatever you want to call him" -- I think the generally agreed-upon name is "War Doctor".

Comment: Huh, I thought it was Capaldi who said “No, sir. All thirteen!”

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It was said off screen, I still think it was Capaldi. chakoteya.net is a fan transcription, not official scripts. Its fairly accurate but noone's perfect.

Comment: @cde - It wasn't Capaldi, it's clearly the other Time Lord responding "No sir--all thirteen!" Go to 2:08 at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0e71KWwE5Fk to rewatch

Comment: @Hypnosifl having just rewatched it before I posted, and again just now, I stand by it being Capaldi. The first part is said off screen when only the General is shown, then the explosion rocks the scene, then the second part is also said offscreen when the tardises are being shown flying around

Comment: @cde - Are you saying you think the "No sir" was said by someone different from the "all thirteen"? It sounds like the same voice (and no Scottish accent like Capaldi's), and the "No sir" line would seem kind of pointless if not followed by the next line.

Comment: @Hypnosifl no, im saying that both were off screen and both sound like Capaldi tends to answer.

Comment: @cde - Again, no Scottish accent, & why would Twelve address the General as "Sir"? Also, as an offscreen voice says "No sir" the General is shown looking to his side--the same side where another Time Lord had repeatedly been shown standing next to him in previous shots (at 0:23, 0:55, 1:04, 1:10, 1:22, 1:35, 1:57)--then after the shot of Capaldi, that same Time Lord says "Sir, the Daleks know that something is happening. They're increasing their firepower!" It sounds like exactly the same voice as the "No sir, all thirteen!" line to me, and the use of "sir" in both lines further supports this.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: ah, you’re right, that’s not Capaldi’s voice. Odd, I remembered it *in* his voice.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for certain that he saw the 12th Doctor. Even if he did, his memory of Time War was hazy, because, as he says to the War Doctor, "The time streams are out of synch"